# How to display another form on select of button

Tags: javascript, forms, select, button

I created jsp which has 2 forms. In UI there are 2 buttons. On select of each button respective form should be displayed. But while trying to do this its not allowing me to display other form on button click. Any sample code such to solve my problem?

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: consider spending some extra time to put caps at the beginning of sentences, "?" at the end of questions and fixing typos...

Comment: @marcgg The poster is probably not a native English speaker.  Had the question been understandable [or included the code sample], one could excuse the lack of grammar.

Comment: Hai try to put both forms with in <div> and hide and show it using javascript

Answer (score 1):

I created example code to do show and hide forms as you explained. Check whether this is the solution for your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script langauge="javascript">
    function showForm1(){
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('form2').style.display="none";  
    }

    function showForm2(){
        document.getElementById('form2').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display="none";  
    }

</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="form1" name="form1">
<h1> Form 1 </h1>   
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
    Form 1 text 1 <input type="text" id="frm1txt1" name="frm1txt1"/> <br>
  Form 1 text 2 <input type="text" id="frm1txt2" name="frm1txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="submit" id="frm1btn1" name="frm1btn1" value="submit"/> <br>
</form>
</div>
<div id="form2" name="form2" style="display:none">
<h1> Form 2 </h1>   
<form id="frm2" name="frm2">
    Form 2 text 1 <input type="text" id="frm2txt1" name="frm2txt1"/> <br>
  Form 2 text 2 <input type="text" id="frm2txt2" name="frm2txt2"/> <br>
  <input type="submit" id="frm2btn1" name="frm2btn1" value="submit"/> <br>
</form>
</div>
<div id="form1" name="form1">
<h1> Show/Hide buttons </h1>    
<form id="ctrl" name="ctrl">
    <input type="button" id="ctrlbtn1" name="ctrlbtn1"  value="Show form 1" onclick="showForm1();"/> &nbsp
  <input type="button" id="ctrlbtn2" name="ctrlbtn2"  value="Show form 2" onclick="showForm2();"/> <br>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```